# No authorization for Azure Data Factory event trigger

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am creating an 'Azure event trigger' in my Azure Data Factory but I am getting the below error.
I found other threads where they mention to check for role/access set to "Owner".
This is the case, I am a bit lost trying to find the solution for this.
Anyone faced this issue before or knows how to solve this?

The client *** with object id *** does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.EventGrid/eventSubscriptions/write' over scope '/subscriptions/ZZZ/resourceGroups/****/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/****/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/eventSubscriptions/****' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.

Thank you

Comment: Hi@Yanni Pattas, have you tried with any other storage account?, could you please edit your question to add the image of the error also, to troubleshoot.

Comment: Hi Rakesh, thanks for your reply. I have found the solution after long trial and error! I had to add "DataFactory" to the "Resource Providers" of my subscription.

Answer (score 0):

You need any of following RBAC settings for storage event trigger:

- Owner role to the storage account
- Contributor role to the storage account
- Microsoft.EventGrid/EventSubscriptions/Write permission to storage account /subscriptions/####/resourceGroups/####/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/storageAccountName

Source: [Authorizing access to Event Grid resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/security-authorization#built-in-roles), [Create a trigger that runs a pipeline in response to a storage event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-event-trigger?tabs=data-factory#role-based-access-control)